# Mysql one to many aggregation filter

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery, having-clause

I have a MYSQL database with 2 tables: users and addresses. One user can have multiple addresses. They look like this:

```
+--------+-------------+
| id     | mame        |
+--------+-------------+
| 1      | Jhon Doe    |
| 2      | Mike Daves  |
| 3      | Sonia White |
+--------+-------------+

+----+--------+---------------+-----------+
| id | userId | address       | status    |
+----+--------+---------------+-----------+
| 1  | 2      | Street 123    | permanent |
| 2  | 2      | Street abc    | temporary |
| 3  | 1      | Street qwerty | disabled  |
| 4  | 3      | str zxcv      | disabled  |
| 5  | 2      | str qazxs     | temporary |
| 6  | 3      | str mnbvc     | disabled  |
+----+--------+---------------+-----------+
```

Is it possible to select all users that have all their addresses 'disabled' using one query?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `not exists`:

```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (
    select 1 from addresses a where a.userid = u.id and a.status <> 'disabled'
)
```

This ensures that the given user has no adress in another status than disabled. You might want to consider an alternative option that uses aggregation:

```
select u.*
from users u
inner join addresses a on a.userid = u.id
group by u.id
having max(a.status <> 'disabled') = 0
```

The main difference is that this ensures that each user has at least one address, while the first query would allow a user that doesn't have any address.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the filter into a join on the Addresses table.

```
SELECT U.*
FROM USERS U
INNER JOIN ADDRESSES A
ON U.ID = A.USERID
AND A.STATUS = 'disabled'
```